# Python 3.5 - method overloading with @overload

Tags: python, python-3.5, overloading

There is an [overloading](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/overloading) package for Python 3.5+.
Whith this package, it's possible to redefined methods, but with distinct type hints and its decorator will find out, which overloaded method should be called.

**Common coding pattern:**

```
class foo:
  def func(param):
    if instance(param, int):
      pass
    elif instance(param, str):
      pass
    elif instance(param, list):
      pass
    else:
      raise ValueError()
```

**With @overload:**

```
class foo:
  @overload
  def func(param: int):
    pass

  @overload
  def func(param: str):
    pass

  @overload
  def func(param: list):
    pass
```

Here is the [documentation](https://overloading.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

---

My questions are:

- How big is the performance impact compared to old style parameter type switching?
- And how does this package access the type hints?

Comment: *Common coding pattern* -- No, it isn't, sorry. Most Python code doesn't need to use `isinstance()`.

Comment: Note that the package is not specific to Python 3.5. Python 3.5 only standardised type hints, but annotations are available from Python 3.0 onwards. The package you link to supports 3.3 and up; your example doesn't use the `typing` module at all.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/bintoro/overloading.py/blob/master/overloading.py) should let you answer the second question (it reads the function annotations, as expected). Looking at the `dispatcher()`, I'd go with 'slower' for the first.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that type hints where supported before 3.5.

Comment: Type hints are just annotations. There was no *standard* for how you'd use annotations for type hinting until the `typing` module was added to 3.5. The sample uses built-in types (`int`, `str`, `list`), so doesn't need `typing`, and I don't think the library supports generics anyway (I doubt it can distinguish between `List[str]` and `Sequence[int]`).

Comment: "Most Python code doesn't need to use isinstance" -- ignoring the 1,300+ uses in the standard library alone

Answer (score 5):

Since python 3.4 there is a core API functionality [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), which allows you to register overloading functions.

From the documentation

```
>>> from functools import singledispatch
>>> @singledispatch
... def fun(arg, verbose=False):
...     if verbose:
...         print("Let me just say,", end=" ")
...     print(arg)

>>> @fun.register
... def _(arg: int, verbose=False):
...     if verbose:
...         print("Strength in numbers, eh?", end=" ")
...     print(arg)

>>> @fun.register
... def _(arg: list, verbose=False):
...     if verbose:
...         print("Enumerate this:")
...     for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
...         print(i, elem)
```

When running the functions above (again from the documentation):

```
>>> fun("Hello, world.")
Hello, world.
>>> fun("test.", verbose=True)
Let me just say, test.
>>> fun(42, verbose=True)
Strength in numbers, eh? 42
>>> fun(['spam', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam'], verbose=True)
Enumerate this:
0 spam
1 spam
2 eggs
3 spam
```

CAUTION: Only the first argument is typed!

Furthermore, there is (since python 3.8) also a equivalent decorator for class methods call [functools.singledispatchmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod)

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to measure it on your own with a real code.

I made a very quick look at the code of this library and conclusion is simple. It uses a lot of reflection (inspect package) and type comparison. inspect package on its own is mostly used by debugging tools - they always slow your code down.

Just look at these lines:

```
complexity = complexity_mapping[id]
if complexity & 8 and isinstance(arg, tuple):
     element_type = tuple(type(el) for el in arg)
elif complexity & 4 and hasattr(arg, 'keys'):
     element_type = (type(element), type(arg[element]))
else:
     element_type = type(element)
```

```
type_hints = typing.get_type_hints(func) if typing else func.__annotations__
types = tuple(normalize_type(type_hints.get(param, AnyType)) for param in parameters)
```

Note that this package if over 7 months old and has only 70 stars. Python is not Java... You'd really hurt python itself with this package :D You'd better implement some core api method that delegates calls to other methods/objects, based on type parameters - just like it should be done with Python.